# What is the difference between "git submodule foreach git pull origin master" and "git pull origin master --recurse-submodules"

Tags: git, recursion, git-submodules

I have a dotfiles repository where all my vim plugins are stored as submodules so they are easy to update when they have changes. I thought these two commands did the same thing, but I noticed this must not be the case.

I knew I had updates to pull down in several submodules so I ran `git pull origin master --recurse-submodules` from the root of the parent repository. It appeared to iterate over each submodule, but only fetch updates from their origin repositories.

When I ran `git submodule foreach git pull origin master` then it actually ran `git pull origin master` within each repository, doing both the fetch and the merge.

What is the point of using `--recurse-submodules`? I'm a little confused about what it's actually trying to do and Google was a bit cryptic with what I found. I thought maybe you smart folks would have a simpler explanation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That option is mainly for **fetching** all the submodule commits, not just pulling one specific branch like master, for reasons detailed in the two following commits:
(note there is a bug fixed in Git 2.11, see at the end of this answer)

For `git pull`, this option has been introduced in ([commit 7dce19d, Nov. 2010, git 1.7.4-rc0)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7dce19d374a37932e9d4c3a6202af407cf5114eb):

> ### `fetch`/`pull`: Add the `--recurse-submodules` option

> Until now you had to call "`git submodule update`" (without `-N|--no-fetch` option) or something like "`git submodule foreach git fetch`" to fetch new commits in populated submodules from their remote.
>
> This could lead to "`(commits not present)`" messages in the output of
> "`git diff --submodule`" (which is used by "`git gui`" and "`gitk`") after
> fetching or pulling new commits in the superproject and is an obstacle for
> implementing recursive checkout of submodules.
> Also "`git submodule update`" cannot fetch changes when disconnected, so it was very easy to forget to fetch the submodule changes before disconnecting only to discover later that they are needed.
>
> This patch adds the "`--recurse-submodules`" option to recursively fetch
> each populated submodule from the url configured in the `.git/config` of the
> submodule at the end of each "`git fetch`" or during "`git pull`" in the
> superproject. The submodule paths are taken from the index.

---

[Commit 88a2197 (March 2011, git 1.7.5-rc1)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/88a21979c5717e3f37b9691e90b6dbf2b94c751a) explains a bit more:

> ### `fetch`/`pull`: recurse into submodules when necessary

> To be able to access all commits of populated submodules referenced by the
> superproject, it is sufficient to only then let "`git fetch`" recurse into a
> submodule when the new commits fetched in the superproject record new
> commits for it.
>
> - **Having these commits present is extremely useful when using the "`--submodule`" option to "`git diff`"** (which is what "`git gui`" and
>   "`gitk`" do since 1.6.6), as all submodule commits needed for creating a
>   descriptive output can be accessed.
> - Also **merging submodule commits (added in 1.7.3) depends on the submodule commits in question being present to work**.
> - Last but not least **this enables disconnected operation when using
>   submodules**, as all commits necessary for a successful "`git submodule update -N`"  will have been fetched automatically.
>
> So we choose this mode as the default for fetch and pull.

---

```
git pull origin master --recurse-submodules 
git submodule foreach git pull origin master
```

The first one should pull, not just fetch, and be equivalent to the second one. Maybe this is a parameter order issue:

```
git pull --recurse-submodules origin master
```

However, it is not the recommended way to update submodule for a given branch: see the following section.

---

Note that the right way to actually pull from master would be to **[register the master branch to the submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18799234/6309)**, making that submodule tracking master:

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<path>.branch <branch>
```

Then a simple `git submodule update --remote --recursive` would be enough.
And the branch to fetch/pull is recorded in the parent repo (in the `.gitmodules` file), so you don't even have to remember which branch you want your submodule to update against.

---

Update Git 2.11 (Q4 2011)

> Having a submodule whose "`.git`" repository is somehow corrupt
> caused a few commands that recurse into submodules loop forever.

See [commit 10f5c52](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10f5c526561604ba9677dc27643b5c9bfad36458) (01 Sep 2016) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 293c232](https://github.com/git/git/commit/293c232ab1dcfa08d650fa9c21377b1ef7b447dc), 12 Sep 2016)</sup>

This last 2016 commits is expended with With Git 2.21 (Q4 2018): "[`git fetch --recurse-submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/5d3635db19c6dff4fb063fabfa4161fd3b8285f0/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L146)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---recurse-submodulesyes%7Con-demand%7Cno))</sup> may not fetch the necessary commit that is bound to the superproject, which is getting corrected.

See [commit be76c21](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be76c2128234d94b47f7087152ee55d08bb65d88) (06 Dec 2018), and [commit a62387b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a62387b3fc9f5aeeb04a2db278121d33a9caafa7), [commit 26f80cc](https://github.com/git/git/commit/26f80ccfc15bb1e591b634173bdb7092da33da12), [commit d5498e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d5498e087175ad7bbb0460a40cfb55cc3726226d), [commit bcd7337](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bcd7337243f4f20091d478c71682d68dd2100207), [commit 16dd6fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/16dd6fe133cc3693f0daad0d10c4f65713e36de4), [commit 08a297b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/08a297bd4996480f0b03830058f413bb24f0d37c), [commit 25e3d28](https://github.com/git/git/commit/25e3d28efd56124b51e02a3f8496401d4e8fb40b), [commit 161b1cf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/161b1cf3bdca7fecf5ec03ffdb74260312cd0229) (28 Nov 2018) by [Stefan Beller (`stefanbeller`)](https://github.com/stefanbeller).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 5d3635d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d3635db19c6dff4fb063fabfa4161fd3b8285f0), 29 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### [`submodule.c`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a62387b3fc9f5aeeb04a2db278121d33a9caafa7): fetch in submodules git directory instead of in worktree
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Stefan Beller</sup>

> Keep the properties introduced in [10f5c52656](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10f5c526561604ba9677dc27643b5c9bfad36458) ("`submodule`: avoid auto-discovery in `prepare_submodule_repo_env()`", 2016-09-01, Git v2.11.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/293c232ab1dcfa08d650fa9c21377b1ef7b447dc) listed in [batch #1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75d03ac84b4061b70ed9739f2a4f640897f2c232)), by fixating the `git` directory of the submodule.

But... "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d627bf6039ac3db5600cb76c738c13bb6e8204d0/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> did not work correctly with nested submodules where the innermost submodule that is not of interest got updated in the upstream, which has been corrected with Git 2.30 (Q1 2021).

See [commit 1b7ac4e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b7ac4e6d4d490b224f5206af7418ed74e490608) (12 Nov 2020) by [Peter Kaestle (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d627bf6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d627bf6039ac3db5600cb76c738c13bb6e8204d0), 25 Nov 2020)</sup>

> ### [`submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b7ac4e6d4d490b224f5206af7418ed74e490608): fix of regression on fetching of non-init subsub-repo
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Peter Kaestle</sup>

> A regression has been introduced by [a62387b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a62387b3fc9f5aeeb04a2db278121d33a9caafa7) ("`submodule.c`: fetch in submodules git directory instead of in worktree", 2018-11-28, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d3635db19c6dff4fb063fabfa4161fd3b8285f0) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a)).
>
> The scenario in which it triggers is when one has a remote repository with a subrepository inside a subrepository like this: `superproject/middle_repo/inner_repo`
>
> Person A and B have both a clone of it, while Person B is not working with the `inner_repo` and thus does not have it initialized in his working copy.
>
> Now person A introduces a change to the `inner_repo` and propagates it through the `middle_repo` and the superproject.
>
> Once person A pushed the changes and person B wants to fetch them using "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1b7ac4e6d4d490b224f5206af7418ed74e490608/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> on superproject level, B's [`git`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1b7ac4e6d4d490b224f5206af7418ed74e490608/Documentation/git-.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-))</sup> call will return with error saying:
>
> Could not access submodule '`inner_repo`' Errors during submodule fetch:>     middle_repo
>
> Expectation is that in this case the inner submodule will be recognized as uninitialized subrepository and skipped by the [`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1b7ac4e6d4d490b224f5206af7418ed74e490608/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> command.
>
> This used to work correctly before '[a62387b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a62387b3fc9f5aeeb04a2db278121d33a9caafa7) ("`submodule.c`: fetch in submodules git directory instead of in worktree", 2018-11-28, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d3635db19c6dff4fb063fabfa4161fd3b8285f0) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a))'.
>
> Starting with [a62387b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a62387b3fc9f5aeeb04a2db278121d33a9caafa7) the code wants to evaluate `"is_empty_dir()`" inside `.git/modules` for a directory only existing in the worktree, delivering then of course wrong return value.
>
> This patch reverts the changes of [a62387b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a62387b3fc9f5aeeb04a2db278121d33a9caafa7) and introduces a regression test.

---

Warning: An earlier attempt to fix "[`git fetch --recurse-submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f3e5dcd66068e38408c76b7b68a5f5112f9189b9/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L168)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---recurse-submodulesyes%7Con-demand%7Cno))</sup> broke another use case; revert it with Git 2.30 (Q1 2021),
until a better fix is found.

See [commit 7091499](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7091499bc0a9bccd81a1c864de7b5f87a366480e) (02 Dec 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f3e5dcd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3e5dcd66068e38408c76b7b68a5f5112f9189b9), 03 Dec 2020)</sup>

> ### [`Revert "submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7091499bc0a9bccd81a1c864de7b5f87a366480e): fix of regression on fetching of non-init subsub-repo"

> This reverts [commit 1b7ac4e6d4d490b224f5206af7418ed74e490608](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b7ac4e6d4d490b224f5206af7418ed74e490608) Ralf Thielow reports that "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/7091499bc0a9bccd81a1c864de7b5f87a366480e/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> with `submodule.recurse` set can result in a bogus and infinitely recursive fetching of the same submodule.

---

With Git 2.30.1 (Q1 2021), "[`git fetch --recurse-submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c977ff440735e2ddc2ef18b18ae9a653bb8650fe/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L168)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---recurse-submodulesyes%7Con-demand%7Cno))</sup> fix (second attempt).

See [commit 505a276](https://github.com/git/git/commit/505a27659638614157a36b218fdaf25fe9fed0ce) (09 Dec 2020) by [Peter Kaestle (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c977ff4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c977ff440735e2ddc2ef18b18ae9a653bb8650fe), 06 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/505a27659638614157a36b218fdaf25fe9fed0ce): fix of regression on fetching of non-init subsub-repo
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Peter Kaestle</sup>
> <sup>CC: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>CC: Philippe Blain</sup>
> <sup>CC: Ralf Thielow</sup>
> <sup>CC: Eric Sunshine</sup>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Philippe Blain</sup>

> A regression has been introduced by [a62387b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a62387b3fc9f5aeeb04a2db278121d33a9caafa7) ("[`submodule.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a62387b3fc9f5aeeb04a2db278121d33a9caafa7/submodule.c): fetch in submodules git directory instead of in worktree", 2018-11-28, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d3635db19c6dff4fb063fabfa4161fd3b8285f0) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a)).
>
> The scenario in which it triggers is when one has a repository with a submodule inside a submodule like this: `superproject/middle_repo/inner_repo`
>
> Person A and B have both a clone of it, while Person B is not working with the `inner_repo` and thus does not have it initialized in his working copy.
>
> Now person A introduces a change to the `inner_repo` and propagates it through the `middle_repo` and the superproject.
>
> Once person A pushed the changes and person B wants to fetch them using "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/505a27659638614157a36b218fdaf25fe9fed0ce/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> at the superproject level, B's git call will return with error saying:
>
> Could not access submodule '`inner_repo`' Errors during submodule fetch:
> middle_repo
>
> Expectation is that in this case the inner submodule will be recognized as uninitialized submodule and skipped by the `git fetch` command.
>
> This used to work correctly before '[a62387b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a62387b3fc9f5aeeb04a2db278121d33a9caafa7) ("[`submodule.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/a62387b3fc9f5aeeb04a2db278121d33a9caafa7/submodule.c): fetch in submodules git directory instead of in worktree", 2018-11-28, Git v2.21.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d3635db19c6dff4fb063fabfa4161fd3b8285f0) listed in [batch #4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b5101f929789889c2e536d915698f58d5c5c6b7a))'.
>
> Starting with [a62387b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a62387b3fc9f5aeeb04a2db278121d33a9caafa7) the code wants to evaluate `"is_empty_dir()`" inside `.git/modules` for a directory only existing in the worktree, delivering then of course wrong return value.
>
> This patch ensures `is_empty_dir()` is getting the correct path of the uninitialized submodule by concatenation of the actual worktree and the name of the uninitialized submodule.
>
> The first attempt to fix this regression, in [1b7ac4e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b7ac4e6d4d490b224f5206af7418ed74e490608) ("`submodules`: fix of regression on fetching of non-init subsub-repo", 2020-11-12, Git v2.30.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d627bf6039ac3db5600cb76c738c13bb6e8204d0) listed in [batch #8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e67fbf927dfdf13d0b21dc6ea15dc3c7ef448ea0)), by simply reverting [a62387b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a62387b3fc9f5aeeb04a2db278121d33a9caafa7), resulted in an infinite loop of submodule fetches in the simpler case of a recursive fetch of a superproject with uninitialized submodules, and so this commit was reverted in [7091499](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7091499bc0a9bccd81a1c864de7b5f87a366480e) (Revert "`submodules`: fix of regression on fetching of non-init subsub-repo", 2020-12-02, Git v2.30.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f3e5dcd66068e38408c76b7b68a5f5112f9189b9) listed in [batch #10](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3a0b884caba2752da0af626fb2de7d597c844e8b)).
> To prevent future breakages, also add a regression test for this scenario.

---

"[`git` fetch `--recurse-submodules` from``](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fa61b7703e7f19f172af3311af8dc04581ecdf69/Documentation/git-fetch.txt#L231)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt-from))</sup> multiple remotes (either from a remote group, or "--all") used to make one extra "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/fa61b7703e7f19f172af3311af8dc04581ecdf69/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> in the submodules, which has been corrected with Git 2.37 (Q3 2022).

See [commit 0353c68](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0353c6881890db1302f0f1bdf85c6076eed61113) (16 May 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit fa61b77](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa61b7703e7f19f172af3311af8dc04581ecdf69), 25 May 2022)</sup>

> ### [`fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0353c6881890db1302f0f1bdf85c6076eed61113): do not run a redundant fetch from submodule
>
> <sup>Reviewed-by: Glen Choo</sup>

> When [7dce19d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7dce19d374a37932e9d4c3a6202af407cf5114eb) ("`fetch/pull`: Add the `--recurse-submodules` option", 2010-11-12, Git v1.7.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4bb4d30095fbc3b1689cc656e71f6a51e43fbd69)) introduced the "--recurse-submodule" option, the approach taken was to perform fetches in submodules only once, after all the main fetching (it may usually be a fetch from a single remote, but it could be fetching from a group of remotes using `fetch_multiple()`) succeeded.
> Later we added "--all" to fetch from all defined remotes, which complicated things even more.
>
> If your project has a submodule, and you try to run "[`git fetch`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0353c6881890db1302f0f1bdf85c6076eed61113/Documentation/git-fetch.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch))</sup> `--recurse-submodule` --all, you'd see a fetch for the top-level, which invokes another fetch for the submodule, followed by another fetch for the same submodule.
> All but the last fetch for the submodule come from a "[`git fetch --recurse-submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/0353c6881890db1302f0f1bdf85c6076eed61113/Documentation/fetch-options.txt#L197)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#Documentation/git-fetch.txt---recurse-submodulesyes%7Con-demand%7Cno))</sup> subprocess that is spawned via the `fetch_multiple()` interface for the remotes, and the last fetch comes from the code at the end.
>
> Because recursive fetching from submodules is done in each fetch for the top-level in `fetch_multiple()`, the last fetch in the submodule is redundant.
> It only matters when `fetch_one()` interacts with a single remote at the top-level.
>
> While we are at it, there is one optimization that exists in dealing with a group of remote, but is missing when "`--all`" is used.
> In the former, when the group turns out to be a group of one, instead of spawning "`git fetch`" as a subprocess via the `fetch_multiple()` interface, we use the normal `fetch_one()` code path.
> Do the same when handing "`--all`", if it turns out that we have only one remote defined.

Comment: See also, on unabsorbed gitdirs: [commit 10a0d6a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10a0d6ae64ad4fec12ab2c1ed13d1791dde60371), [commit 8eb8dcf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/8eb8dcf94643ca6e7c3f040f3e0bf96e11c7ae47), [commit 5df5106](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5df5106e1e8b52ff54c0726ba6919afa4b745980) (09 Sep 2021) by [Jonathan Tan (`jhowtan`)](https://github.com/jhowtan).  
(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 921c795](https://github.com/git/git/commit/921c795c25577e40df1f607a22748332bfb225ea), 06 Oct 2021)

Answer (score 2):

> What is the point of using `--recurse-submodules`?

`--recurse-submodules` will do submodules within a submodule (it's actually *recursive*). `git submodule foreach git pull origin master` will not, it will only do the immediate submodules.

Comment: That makes sense, but I still don't understand why it appeared to only fetch updates in submodules rather than actually do `git pull origin master`.