# PhpStorm - How to pull many GIT repositories in one project

Tags: php, git, phpstorm

Let's say I have one project in *PhpStorm IDE*, and within it I have many Git repositories (1 framework module = 1 repo). I just want to ask how to **pull** changes from all those repositories at once?

I know, that I can commit or push changes on repo massively, but when pulling, it asks me for single Git root.

Comment: Since 2018.10, submodules are supported by IDEAs VCS module: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-64024

It should now just "work" as you pull from the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either:

- use submodule (which can be tricky), to [pull all subrepos as submodules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33835815/6309)

  ```
  git submodule update --rebase --remote
  ```
- or script it as [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/douglas/1287372)

  ```
  find . -name .git -type d \
  | xargs -n1 -P4 -I% git --git-dir=% --work-tree=%/.. remote update -p
  ```

In both instances, you would need to [declare an external tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/configuring-third-party-tools.html) on the [External Tool page](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2016.2/external-tools.html) of PhpStorm.

Comment: I presume, that your 2nd option is a script for linux ;)? (windows here)

Comment: @KrzysztofTrzos No; if you have git installed, all those commands are in `<git>/usr/bin`. If you make a script starting with #!/bin/bash and called `git-xxx` (no extension), you will be able to call it (form PhpStorm if you want) with `git xxx`, and that shell script will be interpreted by the msys2 shell from Git, provided that `git` and that scripts are both in the `%PATH%`.